# Simplify an equality obtained by induction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In a question solved by my professor, he obtained the following result by induction
$$ p_{n+1} = p_n(1-p)+p,~~ \forall n \geq 0 ~~ \&~~ p_0=0$$ then  he simplified it as

\begin{eqnarray}
p_n = \frac{p}{1+1-p} - \frac{p}{1+1-p} (1-p)^n
\end{eqnarray}

But I don't see how this is possible! Can anyone explain to me how he obtained the simplification above.

Comment: In the denominator, it should be $1-(1-p)=p$.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is not correct. The idea is the following :

\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}&=p_n(1-p)+p\\
&=(1-p)\big(p_{n-1}(1-p)+p\big)+p\\
&=p_{n-1}(1-p)^{2}+(1-p)p+p\\
&=(1-p)^2(p_{n-2}(1-p)+p)+(1-p)p+p\\
&=p_{n-2}(1-p)^3+p\left((1-p)^2+(1-p)+1\right).
\end{align*}

Now, we guess that \begin{align*}
p_{n}&=p_{0}(1-p)^n+p\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-p)^i\\
&=p_0(1-p)^n+p\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{p}\\
&=(1-p)^n(p_0-1)+1
\end{align*}

Now make a proof by induction to conclude.

---

Finally, since $p_0=0$, you get $$p_n=1-(1-p)^n.$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I thought there is a direct simplification because he moved directly from the first equality to the second equality in on line!

Comment: I think he let the justification as a homework :-) @Uneétudiante

Comment: @Uneétudiante: I have no idea... but it's better to understand how things works rather than to apply formula that you don't really understand...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a simple trick to solve such a recursion.

First you find the so called equilibrium (or the fixpoint) $b$ of the equation (if it exists) by solving:

$$b=b(1-p) + p \Leftrightarrow b= 1$$

Now, consider the recursion 
$$a_n = p_n - b =p_n -1$$

Pluggin this into the given recursion you get

$$a_{n+1} = a_n(1-p)$$
It follows
$$\Rightarrow a_n = a_0(1-p)^n\stackrel{a_0 = p_0 -1}{\Longrightarrow}p_n = 1-(1-p)^n$$